# Gitlab pages not deploying even with pipeline successful

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-sphinx, gitlab-pages

I am trying to deploy a GitLab Pages static site using html generated by sphinx. My .gitlab-ci.yml file is as follows:

```
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  tags:
    - sphinx
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - sphinx-build -b html ./docs public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

I have a runner on my local computer using a powershell executor, and it runs without issue as you can see here (ignore the previous, failed pipeline):

[image: image showing pipeline success]

However, even though it says it has been successful, the pages option does not display in the repository sidebar and I don't see any link to an actual deployed page. When I download the pipeline artifacts, I am able to open the files locally in my browser and everything shows up perfectly, meaning the html did get generated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you made sure Gitlab Pages is enabled in the Gitlab repository?

Comment: How do I do that? My understanding was that when I first deployed the site, the 'Pages' page would show up in the sidebar under 'Deploy', however this never happened. When I go into my repository settings, it tells me the 'Pages' option has been moved under 'Deploy', but that option is not visible to me.